# Using ContentValues to insert in FOREIGN KEY field

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am using `execSQL` command to insert data into a table that CONTAINS a foreign key.

This is how I am doing currently.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO "+ SunshineContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME +" ( "+
        SunshineContract.WeatherEntry.COL_LOC_KEY + ", "+
        SunshineContract.WeatherEntry.COL_WIND_SPEED+ ", "+
        SunshineContract.WeatherEntry.COL_DEGREE+ ") VALUES ((SELECT " +
        SunshineContract.LocationEntry._ID + " FROM "+ SunshineContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+
        SunshineContract.LocationEntry._ID + " = 1 ), "+
       80, 98);";
sqLiteDatabaseWritable.execSQL(query);
```

I want to use content provider to insert data into my database. But currently, I am not able to use content provider to insert my data because I cannot construct content value for this foreign key field.

```
contentValue.put(SunshineContract.WeatherEntry.COL_LOC_KEY, 'SELECT " +
            SunshineContract.LocationEntry._ID + " FROM "+ SunshineContract.LocationEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+
            SunshineContract.LocationEntry._ID + " = 1 )'
```

Is there any method that can insert data into table CONTAINING FOREIGN KEY using `ContentValues` so that I can use `ContentResolver`?

Comment: In most scenarios, the data will come from web api (json or xml) and you will have to parse that json into some java data object. Then you will only have to put attributes of this java data object as the ContentValue when inserting into a table. Could you explain more the background story of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the `ContentValues` object is to provide values that are cannot be interpreted as expression, to prevent foreign apps from injecting SQL code into the app that implements the content provider.

This means that you cannot look up inserted values dynamically.
You have to read the values from the database first, and put them into a `ContentValues` object (there is a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#cursorRowToContentValues(android.database.Cursor,%20android.content.ContentValues)) for the second step).

If you are accessing your own database, consider not using a content provider at all; using `SQLiteDatabase` would be more flexible.